# Show Configurable Product List by Default In Product Section In Admin

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, product-list

In Magento Admin, when we go to **Catalog > Manage Products**, We see the list of Products of all types by Default as shown as below image:-

[image]

but I want to show only Configurable Type Product by Default View.

Is there a way to do it.? Please anyone help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create a new module with a module declaration file:

app/etc/modules/Shashank_Adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shashank_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Adminhtml/>
            </depends>
        </Shashank_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create your module directory structure and a config.xml:

app/code/local/Shashank/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
</config>
```

We need to rewrite a block inside the admin panel, so let's turn on template hints in the admin.  In our config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <dev>
                <debug>
                    <template_hints>1</template_hints>
                    <template_hints_blocks>1</template_hints_blocks>
                </debug>
            </dev>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

The grid container we want to override is: `Shashank_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid`

Let's rewrite our block with the rewrite node inside our config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_grid>Shashank_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <dev>
                <debug>
                    <template_hints>1</template_hints>
                    <template_hints_blocks>1</template_hints_blocks>
                </debug>
            </dev>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

Let's create a class that rewrites that block.  We will use: `Shashank_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid`.

```
<?php

class Shashank_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid 
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid {

}
```

Now, with our template hints still on, let's check to see that it's being rewritten. 
[image: Rewritten block class]

Now, all we have to do is set our default sort attributes and default filters.  We will do that in the `__construct()` method of our class.

```
<?php

class Shashank_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid 
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid {


    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setDefaultSort('type');
        $this->setDefaultFilter(array('type' => 'configurable'));

    }
}
```

Now, turn off the template hints and see that it's being rewritten.

[image: Default Sort]

I hope this helps.